# i want to make a query to give condition to my board table

Tags: oracle, conditional-statements

```
INSERT INTO ABOARD(BNO, BNAME, BPW, BTITLE, BCONTENT, BDATE, BGROUP,
        BSTEP, BINDENT, COMCNT, ISDEL, HAVEFILE)
        VALUES(#{bno}, #{bname }, #{bpw },
        #{btitle }, #{bcontent }, SYSDATE, GROUPSEQ.NEXTVAL, 0, 0, 0,'N','N')
```

This is my board table.
I want to change the last column `"HAVEFILE"` if I add file to insert the board when I register.

below table is the attachment file. How to join two table or make a query?

```
CREATE TABLE MP_FILE
(
    FILE_NO NUMBER,                         
    BNO NUMBER NOT NULL,                   
    ORG_FILE_NAME VARCHAR2(260) NOT NULL,   
    STORED_FILE_NAME VARCHAR2(36) NOT NULL, 
    FILE_SIZE NUMBER,                       
    REGDATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,  
    DEL_GB VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(FILE_NO)                    
);
```

Comment: An insert can only apply to a single table. You could build a PL/SQL stored procedure to accept all of the inputs and conditionally run a second insert for the second table.

Comment: @pmdba Multitable insert is also possible through `select ... from dual` instead of `insert ... values...`. But for me the requirepent is completely unclear.

Comment: Please, describe what should be done with what input values. "How to join two table or make a query?"... Which query? What is the condition of the join? Second table doesn't have anything that may be a file (no any `blob` or `clob` columns), so this is also not clear, where it should be stored.